# Python, extend a list object to include weights for each element

Tags: python, oop, data-modeling

I am trying to extend a `list` object to also associate with each element, a custom weight. I want to associate a default weight to each element added to the list with the option to modify this weight later. When an element is retrieved, its weight should also be returned.
How should I achieve this via extending the list class? I read a bit about [data modeling](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) in python but I am not sure how to do it with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` emulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writting the more complete answer with collections.abc bellow, and it just occured me you will most likely be fine with an OrderedDict: 
A mapping of key:value pairs (where your "weight"  is your value) which presereves order.

Just do `from collections import OrderedDict` and use it instead of your custom list - replacing any "append(element)" for "mydict[element] = weight"

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

In case you really need a custom list-like object, read on:

**my original idea** - a way to really create a list-like object with custom behavior/elements.

You could technically inherit from `list` for that -  but due to 
technical matters on how Python implements the inter-relationships of 
a list built-in methods, you'd better implement a 
`collections.abc.MutableSequence`  subclass than a subclass of list.

(NB Python 2.x it is just `collections.MutableSequence` - Python 3 adds the "abc" namespace.)

If you check the documentation here - https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html you will see you can get away with a list like object where you only have to implement:
the `__getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __len__, insert` methods, and Python will take care of the rest for you.

And them, you can have an internal Python list to hold your data, in an aggregation pattern - and have it handle all your access for list-like iterations. In this list, simply keep two-tuples or 2-element lists for each data element you want- the first element of which being your element, and the second your desired weight. Then, just add a couple extra methods to allow you to explicitly get/reset your weight parameter.

```
# Python 2/3 compatibility snippet:
try:
    from collections import MutableSequence
except ImportError:
    from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class WList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.data = list(*args, **kw)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if len(value) != 2:
            raise TypeError ("You have to pass a value and a weight")
        self.data[index] = value

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def insert(self, index, value):
        if len(value) !=2:
            raise TypeError ("You have to pass a value and a weight")
        self.data.insert(index, value)

    def set_weight(self, index, weight):
        self.data[index] = (self.data[index][0], weight)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Wlist(%r)" % self.data
```

But....actually, given your question this looks overkill - you probably can just go with an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I achieve this via extending the list class?

Don't do that. This will break the data structure. List is a generic structure of heterogeneous data types. To enforce a pair type for each element would inevitably  violate what a list is. Extending a class or inheritance means you are specializing by adding more capabilities not by restricting it.

What you should actually have done is to create a model with a member of list with either a

- tuple  couplet
- namedtuple
- simple structure with two elements

instead thinking of extending the list is the worst that you could have done.

Comment: where did you get this definition that subclasses should never restrict what parent classes do? For a single example of the absurd of that statement: how do the concept of "abstract" classes work them - since usually the concrete implementations do exactly that (define data types)?  

A List restrict to a particular data type is no less a list - since a list can exist with that subset of data.

Comment: Moreover: If Object Orientation would in anyway restrict what subclasses should do in the light of augmenting/restrict the parent classes, it would make more sense that augmenting them should be the forbidden thing, not the other way around. Fortunatelly it does not restrict either.